# How can I exclude task in playbook file for OS version?

Tags: ansible, rhel, ansible-facts

We have the following example playbook file with `import_playbook` tasks:

```yaml
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage1.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage2.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage3.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage4.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage5.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage6.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage7.yml"
```

Each of above `import_playbook` tasks is installing rpm's on RHEL OS Linux machine

What we need is to exclude `install_stage7.yml` only for **RHEL 7.x**, while the others - `install_stage1.yml - install_stage6.yml`  can be runs on RHEL version 7.9 and 8.6

From my understanding we can use the following

```yaml
 when: ansible_facts['distribution_version'] == "8.6"
```

But not sure how to set that condition for an `import_playbook`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `when` clause to your import:

```yaml
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage1.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage2.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage3.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage4.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage5.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage6.yml"
- import_playbook: "{{playbook_folder}}/install_stage7.yml"
  when: ansible_facts['distribution_version'] == "8.6"
```

Note that the condition is not applied to the import but to every task which is imported. So when the condition is false, all the tasks inside the imported playbook will appear as skipped in the output.